# What are the mathematical assumptions and algorithmic procedure behind MACS2?

Tags: statistics, peak-calling

I wonder if there's some mathematical details that outline what the algorithms does.

Comment: Hi and welcome, it would be helpful if you could put your question in context. What is the objective, how does the algorithm help and why it's published information is insufficient for you.

Comment: Have you read the papers?

Comment: See [here](https://hbctraining.github.io/Intro-to-ChIPseq/lessons/05_peak_calling_macs.html) and [here](https://chipster.csc.fi/manual/macs2.html).

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Thanks.